# Using a TPP223 capacitive board instead of a mechanical button

Tags: button, capacitive

I have this [CSR8645 bluetooth module](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Bluetooth-4-0-CSR8645-Amplifier-Board-5W-5W-APT-X-Stereo-Receiver-Amp-Module/32685530316.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.15.8k9Q5E&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3_10152_10065_10151_10344_10068_10345_10342_10343_51102_10340_10341_10609_10541_5130013_5000013_10084_10083_10304_10307_5080013_10302_10610_10312_10059_10313_10314_10534_100031_10604_10603_10103_10605_5060013_10594_10142_10107,searchweb201603_2,ppcSwitch_2&algo_expid=56005a45-b144-4bad-809f-af636a8792f9-2&algo_pvid=56005a45-b144-4bad-809f-af636a8792f9&transAbTest=ae803_5&rmStoreLevelAB=5) and I wanted to use [TPP223 capacitive buttons](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/50PCS-LOT-NEW-TTP223-Touch-Button-Module-Capacitor-type-Single-Channel-Self-Locking-Touch-Switch-Sensor/32786609480.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.1.arzYat&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3_10152_10065_5000015_10151_10344_10068_10345_10342_10343_51102_10340_10341_5130015_10609_10541_10084_10083_10304_10307_10302_10610_5080015_10312_10059_10313_10314_10534_100031_10604_10603_10103_10605_10594_5060015_10142_10107,searchweb201603_2,ppcSwitch_2&algo_expid=3127dd06-8a0f-49f3-b9bd-f78e5c2f5b9b-0&algo_pvid=3127dd06-8a0f-49f3-b9bd-f78e5c2f5b9b&transAbTest=ae803_5&rmStoreLevelAB=0) for its inputs - vol+, vol-, next, prev, etc., but I am wondering if it will work at all.

The CSR8645 is originally intended to be used with mechanical buttons. Micro buttons [like these](http://www.electroncomponents.com/image/cache/data/switches/EC_SWTactile-500x500.jpg) only make a connection between two of the pins. So their working principle is modulating resistance from `∞Ω` to `0Ω`. On the other hand the capacitive board outputs 5V on its I/O pin when it's touched. So it modulates voltage from `0V` to `5V`. I am wondering if this can destroy the I/O port of the CSR8645 chip, which certainly is not expecting a voltage input where just a connection should be made.

By your opinion can I use the TPP223 directly instead of mechanical buttons or do I have to add something like a relay to emulate a mechanical button.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Bluetooth module uses standard "push button to ground with an internal pull up" for the button, then all you really need to do is use a NPN transistor (and base resistor) on the output of the cap sense board, to pull the button line down to ground.

Comment: So I connect the 5V I/O to transistor base, trough a resistor that will regulate the voltage drop and use the Collector-emitter to "emulate" a button, where the emitter is connected to common ground.
Followup question: the CSR board has separate grounds for Vcc and for the buttons. Is it safe to assume internally it's a common ground, since the TPP223 has to use the Vcc GND, but the transistor has to be connected to the button GND. So they have to be shorted together for this scheme to work.

Comment: Yes, but no. Looks like the csr uses push buttons pulled to VCC through the button to work. A npn solution may not work here. Instead you would use a opto. I'll revise this later.

Comment: If the buttons pull to Vcc and the TPP223 outputs Vcc (it's the same Vcc for both boards) then it should work just connecting the I/O of the TPP to the button port of the CSR? Or am I wrong?

Comment: If they both have the same voltage, then yes. I'll update as soon as I can.

Comment: Alternatively: Can I try if it works without destroying the board?

Before asking here and reading about the way TPP works I did try it once with TPP I/O directly connected to CSR button input, with inconsistent results. Do you think it's safe to make some more tests?

Comment: use a 1K resistor instead of a wire, that should prevent accidental destruction while still passing sufficiently strong button press signals.